# Regex Matching Words in XML Between Two Other Words (Matlab regexp)

Tags: regex, xml, matlab, parsing

I'm trying to parse an xml file using Matlab regexp. Specifically I like to retrieve an array of all incidences of the word "curvepoint" occuring between 
"deposits" and "/deposits". So for the xml below it should be a [6x1] array like

"

```
<curvepoint>
<curvepoint>
<curvepoint>
<curvepoint>
<curvepoint>
<curvepoint>
```

"

My attempt below doesn't work as there is lots of other text interspersed between each "curvepoint" word-incidence and the look-aheads/backs, but I don't know how to handle for this.

```
regexp(XMLText,'(?<=<deposits>)(<curvepoint>)(?=</deposits>)','match')'
```

XMLText is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<interestRateCurve>
   <effectiveasof>2016-11-07</effectiveasof>
   <currency>EUR</currency>
   <baddayconvention>M</baddayconvention>
   <deposits>
      <daycountconvention>ACT/360</daycountconvention>
      <snaptime>2016-11-04T15:00:00.000Z</snaptime>
      <spotdate>2016-11-09</spotdate>
      <calendars>
         <calendar>none</calendar>
      </calendars>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>1M</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2016-12-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>-0.00373</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>2M</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2017-01-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>-0.00339</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>3M</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2017-02-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>-0.00312</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>6M</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2017-05-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>-0.00213</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>9M</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2017-08-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>-0.0013</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>1Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2017-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>-0.00071</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
   </deposits>
   <swaps>
      <fixeddaycountconvention>30/360</fixeddaycountconvention>
      <floatingdaycountconvention>ACT/360</floatingdaycountconvention>
      <fixedpaymentfrequency>1Y</fixedpaymentfrequency>
      <floatingpaymentfrequency>6M</floatingpaymentfrequency>
      <snaptime>2016-11-04T15:00:00.000Z</snaptime>
      <spotdate>2016-11-09</spotdate>
      <calendars>
         <calendar>none</calendar>
      </calendars>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>2Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2018-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>-0.00157</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>3Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2019-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>-0.00115</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>4Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2020-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>-0.00059</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>5Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2021-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>0.00017</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>6Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2022-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>0.00108</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>7Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2023-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>0.0021</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>8Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2024-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>0.00316</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>9Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2025-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>0.00419</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>10Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2026-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>0.00513</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>12Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2028-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>0.00673</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>15Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2031-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>0.00838</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>20Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2036-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>0.00966</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
      <curvepoint>
         <tenor>30Y</tenor>
         <maturitydate>2046-11-09</maturitydate>
         <parrate>0.01006</parrate>
      </curvepoint>
   </swaps>
</interestRateCurve>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Never use regex to parse XML.** At best the solution will be brittle. Use a real XML parser instead.

In MATLAB, use [xmlread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlread.html), [xmlwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlwrite.html), and [xslt](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xslt.html) functions to read, write, and transform XML.

Note that the [MathWorks blog has XML posts](https://www.mathworks.com/search/site_search.html?q=xml&c%5B%5D=blogs) on using these functions in MATLAB.

Comment: thanks kj, I don't don't have the time to work on matlab's xml functionality to achieve this (this is only tiny tiny part of my "project"). I think also the regex will only be as brittle as the logic of the regex is vague - an regexp experienced coder should be able to find a rigorous expression. I spent time making this question quite specific in the effort to get a specific solution.

Comment: Do as you wish, but you wouldn't be asking this question if you appreciated exactly how much of a mismatch regex is for parsing XML, both fundamentally and practically. These risks are well documented elsewhere; I have less time to rehash those risks than you have to learn to do it the right way.